# Update value of TextBox after any of multiple other TextBoxes have updated

Tags: excel, vba, controls

I am working on a League Manager for my local billiard hall.

I created a UserForm to enter scores and I'm looking for an easier way to code up my controls.
I have a TextBox to display the sum of values contained in other TextBoxes in the UserForm.
Is there a way to update this sum if any of the TextBoxes change or are updated?

My research has pointed me in the direction of using a class for TextBoxes but what I've read is that the WithEvents modifier doesn't support Change or Before/After Update.
I haven't found an example that solves my problem or rather an example that works for only the TextBoxes I want to group, not ALL TextBoxes.
I could write a subroutine (like below) for each of the TextBoxes but I feel there is a more efficient way.

```vb
Private Sub txtPlayer1_1_Score6_AfterUpdate()
    txtPlayer1_1_Total.Value = CInt(txtPlayer1_1_Score1.Value) + _
                               CInt(txtPlayer1_1_Score2.Value) + _
                               CInt(txtPlayer1_1_Score3.Value) + _
                               CInt(txtPlayer1_1_Score4.Value) + _
                               CInt(txtPlayer1_1_Score5.Value) + _
                               CInt(txtPlayer1_1_Score6.Value)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: you could use text changed to check for a text change

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I'm aware there is a TextBox_Change() method but that's basically the same as the above code. Is text changed different?

Comment: While the BeforeUpdate and AfterUpdate events are not available in a class module, the Change event is definitely available.  However, the Change event would be triggered with each keystroke, which wouldn't be too efficient.  And, you might find it to be somewhat of a nuisance.  I would suggest instead to attach your code to a command button.  Once clicked, it would do the necessary error checking and summing.

Comment: I'm trying to make this as fluid as possible for the guy using this. Adding a command button just seems like more a nuisance and would ruin the flow of entering the scores of each player. I came across this                                                                
Private Sub AnyTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Textbox1.TextChanged, Handles Textbox2.TextChanged, Handles Textbox3.TextChanged, Handles Textbox4.TextChanged, ... Handles Textbox81.TextChanged

End Sub

Comment: But my editor is giving a syntax error on the keyword Handles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that uses the Change event in a class module.  It assumes that the userform is named UserForm1, so change the name accordingly.  Also, you may want to change how the code behaves, depending on your preference, but at least it's a start.

First, in the Visual Basic Editor, insert a class module (Visual Basic Editor >> Insert >> Class Module).  Then, under the Properties window (F4), name your class clsTextBox.  Then, place the following code into the code module for the class...

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents tb As MSForms.textBox

Private Sub tb_Change()
    Dim textboxCollection As Collection
    Dim textBox As clsTextBox
    Dim total As Long
    Set textboxCollection = UserForm1.getTextBoxCollection()
    total = 0
    For Each textBox In textboxCollection
        If Len(textBox.tb.Value) > 0 Then
            If IsNumeric(textBox.tb.Value) Then
                total = total + textBox.tb.Value
            Else
                With textBox.tb
                    .SetFocus
                    .SelStart = 0
                    .SelLength = Len(.Value)
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next textBox
    UserForm1.txtPlayer1_1_Total.Value = total
End Sub
```

Then, place the following code into code module for the userform...

```
Option Explicit

Dim m_textboxCollection As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    Dim textBox As clsTextBox
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If InStr(1, ctrl.Name, "Score", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set textBox = New clsTextBox
            Set textBox.tb = ctrl
            m_textboxCollection.Add textBox
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub

Public Property Get getTextBoxCollection()
    Set getTextBoxCollection = m_textboxCollection
End Property
```

I would suggest, though, that you use a label instead of a textbox for your total so that the user won't be able to change its value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get a "Type mismatch" error when I run this but I feel it's very close to what I'm looking for. The compiler isn't telling me where the error is occurring.

Comment: The error is happening at the "Set textBox.tb = ctrl" line in the UserForm code.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! Thank you. I'm actually proud of myself for solving the "Type mismatch" error on my own. It was do to me having named some labels in the UserForm with "Score" in them. Labels are not TextBoxes, hence the error. All I did was change the InStr function to look for "_Score" instead which I only have in the names of TextBoxes. Again, thank you very much. Do you have any recommendations for a great VBA book with examples like this?

Comment: That's great, I'm glad you were able to solve the mismatch error.  The one book that I can recommend is one by John Walkenbach called Microsoft Office Excel Power Programming with VBA.  Cheers!